# How to verify the SSL connection when calling a URI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, https, openssl

I am developing a web application that is authenticated using CAS (A single-sign-on solution: http://www.ja-sig.org/wiki/display/CAS/Home).

For security reasons, I need two things to work:

- The communication between CAS and my application needs to be secure
- My application needs to accept the certification coming from CAS, so that I can guarantee that the CAS responding is the real CAS server

This is what I got so far:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://www.google.com/accounts")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = (uri.scheme == 'https')
https.verify_mode = (OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER)
raw_res = https.start do |conn|
  conn.get("#{uri.path}?#{uri.query}")
end
```

This works just great in Mac OS X. When I try to reach an insecure URI, it raises an exception, and when I try to reach a secure URI, it allows me normally, just like expected.

The problem starts when I deploy my application on my Linux server. I tried in both Ubuntu and Red Hat. Independent of what URI I try to reach, it always raises this exception:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
    from (irb):7
```

I think this have something to do with my installed OpenSSL package, but I can't be sure. This are my installed OpenSSL packages:

```
openssl.x86_64                              0.9.8e-12.el5              installed
openssl-devel.x86_64                        0.9.8e-12.el5              installed
```

I tried using HTTParty as well, but it just ignores the SSL certificate.

I hope someone can help me, or tell me about a gem that works the way I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that there's a difference in the Certificate Authorities file. Try setting `https.ca_file` to another pem file, [like maybe this one](http://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/certs/cacert.pem), and ensure that your cert's CA is in that list.

Or, perhaps one or both of the machines' clocks are wrong. (via [this page](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Certificates_And_Security))

> Check that the clocks between the
>   puppetmaster and client are in sync,
>   if the client is behind when the
>   certificate was generated, then the
>   client sees that the start date of the
>   certificate is in the future and
>   therefore is invalid. Just for
>   reference you can find out this info
>   from the cert using the following:
>
> openssl x509 -text -noout -in
>   /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/hostname.tld.pem
>   | grep -A2 Validity
>
> ```
>     Validity
>         Not Before: Apr 19 23:21:29 2009 GMT
>         Not After : Apr 18 23:21:29 2014 GMT
> ```

Answer (score -4):

http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

Comment: This will do exactly the opposite  of what I'm looking for. I want it to verify SSL, not discard.

Comment: Not only is that the Opposite of the question asked -- It is a VERY-bad-security idea.  In particular, if you are working "_in the middle_" say on a web site.  Your client or client's client information can be hacked and you are legally responsible for a breech.